# Printing date in java with ordinal characters

Tags: java

Is there a way in Java you could format a date with the ordinal characters at the end of day

something like :

1st of july ?

I have searching all over and could not find it anywhere?

Answer (score 7):

There is no automatic way I'm afraid.
You need to use some kind of custom method. Here is one I used in the past:

```
String getOrdinal(final int day) {
    if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (day % 10) {
        case 1: return "st";
        case 2: return "nd";
        case 3: return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing something like this is definitely the easiest way to go I believe.

Comment: Did Java 8 DateTimeFormatter provide anything for this? (I don't see it myself)