# Switch Statement doing opposite to

Tags: java

I have a case statement here that I use:

```
  String color = this.getPlayer().getColor();

    System.out.print("\nCOLOR IS: " + color + "\n");

    switch(color) {
        case "Black":
            /*
            we need the front two diag pieces. Are they opposition color?

             */

            Piece p = board[fromX - 1][fromY - 1].getPiece();
            if ((p != null) & (p.getPlayer().getColor() != this.getPlayer().getColor())) {
                if (p instanceof Pawn) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            p = board[fromX + 1][fromY - 1].getPiece();
            if ((p != null) & (p.getPlayer().getColor() != this.getPlayer().getColor())) {
                if (p instanceof Pawn) {
                    return true;
                }}

        case "White":
            System.out.print("\n\nYOU ARE IN WHITE CASE STATEMENT");



            p = board[fromX - 1][fromY + 1].getPiece();
            if ((p != null) & (p.getPlayer().getColor() != this.getPlayer().getColor())) {
                if (p instanceof Pawn) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            p = board[fromX + 1][fromY + 1].getPiece();
            if ((p != null) & (p.getPlayer().getColor() != this.getPlayer().getColor())) {
                if (p instanceof Pawn) {
                    return true;
                }
            }}
```

and running this code will land me in the white case even though the String color variable is definitely Black. 
here is proof of this fact

```
    COLOR IS: Black


YOU ARE IN WHITE CASE STATEMENTException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at King.underThreat(King.java:233)
    at Game.move(Game.java:118)
    at main.main(main.java:19)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This means that `this.getPlayer().getColor()` is definitely "black" and that it is going into the opposite case in the switch statement that I have set up. Can anyone please explain the situations in which this would occur? it seems very illogical to me.

Comment: add a `break;` after you're done handling black.

Comment: You're missing `break;` at the end of each of your `case:`

Comment: understood, will do that. But it still does not make logical sense that this occurs no?

Comment: Or in other words, it's executing both cases (not just the white) because the black case is falling through due to the lack of `break`. Put a print in the black case as well to see.

Comment: `As break statement is optional. If we omit the break, execution will continue on into the next case. It is sometimes desirable to have multiple cases without break statements between them. For example, consider the updates version of above program, it also display whether a day is a weekday or a weekend day.` From: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-in-java/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a switch statement, why are all the cases being executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058995/in-a-switch-statement-why-are-all-the-cases-being-executed)

Comment: Understood guys thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You never have a `break` in your code:

```
switch (color) {
case "Black":
    // Code
    break;

case "White":
    // Code
    break;
}
```

Comment: does this mean that without the break the JVM finds a case and will execute from that point on, thus always visiting the proceeding case statements if there is no break?

Comment: @entercaspa Without breaks, it will execute every case under the case that it matched against.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you did not use `break`, without it, it will goes down to all the cases. The correct syntax is:

```
switch(color) {
    case "Black":
    // your code
       break;
    case "White":
    // your code
       break;
}
```