# Every case in switch is triggered in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem to solve a bug in my code regarding to switch case statements.

```
testvalue = 1

switch(testvalue){
                case 1:
                    console.log("Case 1 loaded");
                case 2:
                    console.log("Case 2 loaded");
                case 3: 
                    console.log("Case 3 loaded");
                case 4: 
                    console.log("Case 4 loaded");
                case 5:
                    console.log("Case 5 loaded");
                default:
                    console.log("Default case loaded");
            }
```

After I run this part of code, I get the following result in the console:

> "Case 1 loaded" "Case 2 loaded" "Case 3 loaded" "Case 4 loaded" "Case
> 5 loaded" "Default case loaded"

I dont understand why JavaScript is going into every case I have even tho I have 1 as my testvalue and none of the other cases after the first one should be triggered. Is it because testvalue is getting treated as a boolean?
When I apply "typeof" to testvalue I get "number" as a result so JS should know that this is not a boolean.

I hope this one is pretty easy to solve. Thats for any kind of help!

Comment: please put `break;` after every case except default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement multiple cases in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break)

Comment: Its a nice additional info I just checked out, thank you for the information!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a switch statement, why are all the cases being executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058995/in-a-switch-statement-why-are-all-the-cases-being-executed)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript supports C style [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) case fall through, which means unless there is a break specified, it will continue to execute all the subsequent cases.

In order to execute only one set of statements in a case block, you must end it with `break;`.

Comment: Almost 100% guarantee this is a duplicate of some other question, and it also can be considered to be a problem caused by a typo.

Comment: Akash Kava answered my question, thank you very much. Also Tim, its not a dublicate, I was already searching for it but could not find any same case of error I had.

Comment: I simply did not understand why I should need to put a break into every case at the end but with the help from Akash and tedd I got it now. Thx again!