# What are switch expressions and how are they different from switch statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-14, switch-expression

As part of Java SE 12, [`switch` expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) were introduced and since Java SE 14, they have been standardized. How are they different from `switch` statements?

Comment: What does standardized mean vs. introduced?

Comment: @rogerdpack This must refer to switch expressions being introduced as Preview feature in JDK 12 - fully usable and complete, enabled through the compiler options, still amenable to (breaking) change in future versions based on user feedback. In JDK 14 this was consolidated as a standard feature that won't change anymore in future versions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### The `switch` statement:

Unlike the `if/else if/else` statement, a `switch` statement can have a number of possible execution paths. A `switch` works with the primitive types, `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int`, their respective wrapper types (`Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, and `Integer`), enumerated types, and the `String` type<sup>1</sup>. While an `if-else` statement is used to test expressions based on ranges of values or conditions, a `switch` statement is used to test expressions based only on a single value.

**Demo**

```
enum PaymentStatus {
    UNPAID, PARTPAID, PAID, DISPUTED, UNKNOWN;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "";
        PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.PARTPAID;

        switch (paymentStatus) {
        case UNPAID:
            message = "The order has not been paid yet. Please make the minimum/full amount to procced.";
            break;
        case PARTPAID:
            message = "The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.";
            break;
        case PAID:
            message = "The order is fully paid. Please choose the desired items from the menu.";
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid payment status: " + paymentStatus);
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.
```

### The `switch` expression:

The `switch` expression was introduced with Java SE 12. However, it remained as a **Preview** feature in Java SE 12 and 13 and finally got standardized with Java SE 14. [Like any expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), `switch` expressions evaluate to a single value, and can be used in statements. It also introduced "arrow `case`" labels eliminating the need for `break` statements to prevent fall through. As of Java SE 15, there is no change in the supported data types (mentioned in the `switch` statement section above).

**Demo**

```
enum PaymentStatus {
    UNPAID, PARTPAID, PAID, DISPUTED, UNKNOWN;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.PARTPAID;

        String message = switch (paymentStatus) {
        case UNPAID -> "The order has not been paid yet. Please make the minimum/full amount to procced.";
        case PARTPAID -> "The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.";
        case PAID -> "The order is fully paid. Please choose the desired items from the menu.";
        default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid payment status: " + paymentStatus);
        };

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.
```

### The `switch` expression with `yield`:

Since Java SE 13, you can use `yield` statement, instead of the arrow operator (->), to return a value from a `switch` expression.

**Demo**

```
enum PaymentStatus {
    UNPAID, PARTPAID, PAID, DISPUTED, UNKNOWN;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.PARTPAID;

        String message = switch (paymentStatus) {
        case UNPAID:
            yield "The order has not been paid yet. Please make the minimum/full amount to procced.";
        case PARTPAID:
            yield "The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.";
        case PAID:
            yield "The order is fully paid. Please choose the desired items from the menu.";
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid payment status: " + paymentStatus);
        };

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The order is partially paid. Some features will not be available. Please check the brochure for details.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The support for `String` was added with JDK 7

Comment: "Unlike the if/else if/else statement, a switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths" sounds like `switch` could execute multiple cases for one switch. If you mean that `switch` supports fallthrough it would be much more clear to mention that explicitly. Other than that if/else if/else is just different syntax compared to switch statement because you can easily convert any switch statement without fallthrough to if/else if/else format.

Answer (score 15):

Nice writeup!  But I might also add the ability to have multiple cases for a single case statement.  The following example is very contrived (there are many better ways to achieve it).  It does a simple frequency count of the vowels, digits, consonants, and other characters in a string.

```
int count[] = new int[4];

String s = "829s2bi9jskj*&@)(so2i2ksso";

for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
      int i = switch (c) {
                case  'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' -> 0;
                case  '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' -> 1;
                case  'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                      'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w',
                      'x', 'y', 'z' -> 2;
                default -> 3;
      };
      count[i]++;
}
System.out.printf("vowels  - %d%n", count[0]);
System.out.printf("digits  - %d%n", count[1]);
System.out.printf("consonants - %d%n", count[2]);
System.out.printf("other   - %d%n", count[3]);
```

Prints

```
vowels  - 4
digits  - 7
consonants - 10
other   - 5
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding to existing answers: `yield` can also be used with `->` and its main purpose is to allow the use of a block when a single expression is not sufficient for a given case:

```
var test = switch (value) {
    case A -> 1;
    case B -> 2;
    case C -> {
        System.err.println("neither A nor B"); // or some calculation
        yield -1;
    }
}
```

I would also mention [JEP-354](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) where the switch expression is proposed and described.
Formal specification can be found, as always in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answers one can look at the current “shortfalls” with switch statement which switch expression solve:

***Switch Statement:***

- Issue 1: Accidental Fall-through
- Issue 2: Variable scoping
- Issue 3: No return value

***Switch expression:***

- No fallthrough
- Combined constants
- Blocked scope
- Return yield

### EXAMPLE:

***Switch Statement:***

```
private static void oldSwitchStatement(String month) {

    int i = 0;
    String quarter = "";

    switch (month) {
        case "JAN":
        case "FEB":
        case "MAR":
            i = i + 1;
            quarter = "Q1";
            // break;
        case "APR":
        case "MAY":
        case "JUN":
            i = i + 2;
            quarter = "Q2";
            // break;
        case "JUL":
        case "AUG":
        case "SEP":
            i = i + 3;
            quarter = "Q3";
            // break;
        case "OCT":
        case "NOV":
        case "DEC":
            i = i + 4;
            quarter = "Q4";
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown case");
    }

    System.out.println("QUARTER: "+ i + " "+ quarter);
}
```

***Switch Expression***

```
private static String newSwitchExpressionYield(String month) {

    return switch (month) {
        case "JAN", "FEB", "MAR" -> "Q1";
        case "APR", "MAY", "JUN" -> {
            System.out.println("Using yield.");
            yield "Q2";
        }
        case "JUL", "AUG", "SEP" -> "Q3";
        case "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" -> "Q4";
        default -> "Unknown case";
    };
}
```

To test the above pass `oldSwitchStatement("APR");` and `newSwitchExpressionYield("APR");` and see the resutls.