# Switch expressions: Why does Java consider my break - String lines not to be statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-13

Trying to understand switch expression and came up with the following code. In fact I get "not a statement" error for all "break - String" combinations. What am I doing wrong?

```
String i = switch(value) {
            case 0:
                break "Value is 0";
            case 1:
                break "Value is 1";
            case 2:
                break "Value is 2";
            default:
                break "Unknown value";
        };
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html: "To specify their value, use the new yield statement instead of the break statement."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct keyword to use is `yield` to return a value in a switch expression: it was introduced as an enhancement in [JDK 13](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354). Alternatively since your expressions are all simple you can use the shorthand arrow notation:

```
String i = switch(value) {
    case 0 -> "Value is 0";
    case 1 -> "Value is 1";
    case 2 -> "Value is 2";
    default -> "Unknown value";
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am aware of arrow notation and was able to produce it without error. I was not aware about yield. Strange, I'm learning with oReilly Learning Java book and it claims to be fully updated for Java 14. That was misleading. Your answer however sorted my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! @vdmclcv - You can also check [What are switch expressions and how are they different from switch statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65657169/10819573)

Answer (score -2):

For JDK < 13

```
    String i;
    switch(value) {
        case 0:
            i = "Value is 0";
            break;
        case 1:
            i = "Value is 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            i = "Value is 2";
            break;
        default:
            i = "Unknown";
    };
```

For JDK > 13:

```
String i = switch(value) {
    case 0 -> "Value is 0";
    case 1 -> "Value is 1";
    case 2 -> "Value is 2";
    default -> "Unknown";
};
```

Your example - is the combination of sitch statement and expression :)

Comment: Can you modify your answer @yegorf, it is misleading

Comment: But what you're showing is a switch statement not a switch expression and yes, his example comes from Java

Comment: Not all java versions have a switch expression.

Comment: What you're saying is `Your example is not from Java language`, well, yes it is. Please modify your answer as this one is misleading