# How to set an error message when a field is empty?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am doing an exercise in Java. How can I add an error message if the field `Country` is blank?

This is part of my code:

```
public class Nationality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Country = "Mexico";
        switch(Country) {
            case "Mexico":
                System.out.println("Mexican");
                break;
            case "Poland":
                System.out.println("Polish");
                break;
            case "USA":
                System.out.println("US citizen");
                break;
         etc. etc.
```

Comment: switch statements have a "default" case, I assume this is what you are looking for, so just throw an exception when it hits that? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Or just do the check before the switch statement with an if statement and then throw an exception

Comment: A remark: if the number of possible field values is known (and not too large), we can also use an `Enum` to represent the values.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to do such validations is using [guard clauses](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-01/guard-clauses/).

Do **not** use the `default` part of the `switch` statement for this (as suggested in the comments). It is **not** the way of a programmer to to check for invalid values **after** some action. No - we catch them right away and then proceed knowing that all is well!

#### Before Java 21

Before Java version 21 this means an `if` statement, which prevents further code execution by doing a `return` or throwing an `exception` if the condition is met:

```java
public class Nationality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String country = "Mexico";

        if (country == null || country.isBlank())
            throw new RuntimeException("country must not be null or blank!");

        switch(country) {
            case "Mexico":
                System.out.println("Mexican");
                break;
            case "Poland":
                System.out.println("Polish");
                break;
            case "USA":
                System.out.println("US citizen");
                break;
         etc. etc.
```

It's recommended, because it makes your code a lot more readable than nesting the whole `switch` statement inside an `if` statement (which would be the classic alternative).

#### From Java 21 Onwards

As of Java 21 [`case null` is supported](https://belief-driven-design.com/looking-at-java-21-switch-pattern-matching-14648/#switch--null). Then there's also a [new way to write guard clauses inside the `switch` statement](https://belief-driven-design.com/looking-at-java-21-switch-pattern-matching-14648/#guard-clauses).

As a result, you can now move your guard clause right into your `switch` statement:

```java
public class Nationality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String country = "Mexico";

        switch (country) {
            case null -> throw new RuntimeException("country must not be null!");
            case String s when s.isBlank() ->
                throw new RuntimeException("country must not be blank!");
            case "Mexico" -> System.out.println("Mexican");
            case "Poland" -> System.out.println("Polish");
            case "USA" -> System.out.println("US citizen");
            default -> System.out.println("None of the above");
        }
```

Unfortunately, you can't merge the `case null` with the `case String s when s.isBlank()` (yet).

Note that I used the more modern arrow syntax here, which [eliminates the need for `break` statements and is a standard feature since Java 14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65657170/20594090).

#### Comparison

Both approaches are perfectly valid - the choice is up to you.

The difference lies mainly in the mindset behind it:

- with the `if` statement before the `switch` ("Before Java 21"), you are preventing invalid values from entering your defined process.
- with the `null` and `isBlank()` checks at the top of the `switch` ("From Java 21 Onwards"), you are treating those checks as part of the process

  - but still cleanly put at the top and recognizable as guard clauses

Personally, in this case, I find the first option with the `if` statement more readable.
But if it was *only* a `null` check (and no blank check), I'd immediately go for the second option.

##### Side notes:

- Consider naming your String object `country` instead of `Country`, to follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) (variable names should start lowercase and then use camelCase).
- I used the String method [`isBlank()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-blank-empty-strings#string-trim) that exists since Java 11.
  With lower Java versions you can do the same via [`country == null || country.trim().isEmpty()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-blank-empty-strings#string-trim), which is [less efficient than using `isBlank()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-blank-empty-strings#string-trim) though.

Comment: Of note: Java 21+ supports `case null`. As such, `case null: default: throw new ...` can be used to capture _both_ missing _and_ unknown values in a `switch` statement.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic Great hint, thanks for the remark! I updated my answer with a Java 21+ solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a giant switch statement, you should use a Map. Then the code becomes easy write and understand.

```
public class Nationality {
    private static final Map<String, String> COUNTRIES = Map.of(
        "Mexico", "Mexican",
        "Poland", "Polish",
        "USA", "US citizen",
        // etc
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String country = "Mexico";

        if (country == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("country must not be null!");
        } else if (country.isBlank()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("country must not be blank!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(COUNTRIES.getOrDefault(country, "None of the above"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am learning Java and the topic is 'switch' that's why I need to know how, using switch, I can add the error message in case the field Country is blank